# How would I detect collision direction between a point and a rectangle?

Tags: python, math, collision-detection, game-physics

I know that if I wanted to check if a point is inside a rectangle, I can do something like:

```
def pointRect(px, py, rx, ry, rw, rh):
    #Is the point inside the rectangle's bounds?
    if (px >= rx and        #Right of the left edge AND
        px <= rx + rw and   #Left of the right edge AND
        py >= ry and        #Below the top AND
        py <= ry + rh):     #Above the bottom
            return True
    return False
```

If the point is moving and the rectangle is fixed, the above works fine for detecting collision.

How then would I determine the *direction* the point hits the rectangle from?

I can only seem to find examples of how to do this if the moving object is also a rectangle.

Comment: Store the point's last two or three positions and create a vector?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? As in create a shape using the last few positions of the single point?

Comment: see the duplicate question and answer, it is very similar to yours, and the same method should work.